# SQL Statement to UPDATE three characters in a string

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, stored-procedures, database-migration

How to take a string from a row in a column named 'link', and modify it by adding three letters to a specific index position in the string.

Specific example:

I want to select the value `'http://www.hello.no'` and `UPDATE` it with `'http://www-x1.hello.no'` using SQL statement(s).
Lets say the index position where '-x1' starts at will always be 10.

This needs to be accomplished using PostgreSQL. But if you can capture the logic with a generic SQL statement then great. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Postgresql has a function for doing replacements with patterns called `regexp_replace`. You can use that function like this:

```
UPDATE my_table
SET link = regexp_replace(link, 'www', 'www-x1')
WHERE <...>
```

Of course you could do it with the straight string manipulation, too:

```
UPDATE my_table
SET link = left(link, 10) || '-x1' || substring(link from 10)
WHERE <...>
```

Answer (score 0):

This does what you ask for:

```
update the_table
   set the_column = left(the_column, 10) || '-x1' || substring(the_column, 10);
```

however I'm not sure that this is what you want. It seems you want to insert the `'-x1'` in front of the first `.` which would be something different.